# Best place for ASP.NET web application logs

Tags: asp.net

What is the recommended folder to write the web application log files?

c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Logs, App_Data folder... ?

Comment: You need to indicate if you are referring to IIS access logs or log entries generated by your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard location for application logs. Use what you and your team agree on.

IIS 6 logs normally live in `%WINDIR%\Logs`.

IIS 7 seems to default to `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer App_Data which is always writable by design and closed to access from the browser by ASP.NET filtering module.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider keeping your logs on a separate drive to the one that contains your Windows installation. This is because it is possible for your log files eventually to use all the space on your system drive, at which point your server will stop responding - keeping logs on a separate drive avoids this issue.

Comment: I was thinking primarily of IIS logs when I wrote this but it's a potential problem for any kind of logging.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to give special permissions to that folder , so make sure (for security reasons) it resides outside the web application folder

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on you where you want it to store. i will recommend you to use  elmah
(Error Logging Modules and Handlers for ASP.NET) which gives you flexibility to handle logs

Chetan
http://chetanwarade.wordpress.com/

Comment: Please do not promote your blog like this - it is frowned upon and doesn't add anything to the answer.